# Problem running Micronaut example in my own environment

Tags: kubernetes, micronaut

I am trying to run the following repository in my own environment:
https://github.com/piomin/sample-micronaut-kubernetes

I applied the kubernetes yamls file in each k8s directory using kubectl apply -f file.yaml
as indicated in the tutorial I also did

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:default
```

tutorial is available at https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/01/07/guide-to-micronaut-kubernetes/

when I run Skaffold dev on the employee folder I will get the error:

- unable to decode "STDIN": Object 'Kind' is missing in '{"data":{"application.yaml":"mongodb:\n  collection: employee\n  database: admin\nin-memory-store.enabled: true\ntest.employees:\n  - id: 1\n    organizationId: 1\n    departmentId: 1\n    name: John Smith\n    age: 22\n    position: Developer\n  - id: 2\n    organizationId: 1\n    departmentId: 2\n    name: Paul Walker\n    age: 33\n    position: Tester"}}'
- unable to decode "STDIN": Object 'Kind' is missing in '{"data":{"mongodb.uri":"bW9uZ29kYjovL21pY3JvbmF1dDptaWNyb25hdXRfMTIzQG1vbmdvZGI6MjcwMTcvYWRtaW4="}}'

It does look like Kind is indeed missing in both data sections, what should be the value of kind here? I believe my version of kubernetes is more recent than the one used in the tutorial. Is there any website/reference I could use to fix the discrepencies?

- Minikube is 1.29.0
- Skaffold is 2.1.0
- Kubectl: Client Version: v1.26.1
  Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
  Server Version: v1.26.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the file was using windows line endings instead of unix line endings...